# How to save file into a path containing special characters such as '＆'? ('＆' which is different from '&' typed in English Keyboard)

Tags: r, path, special-characters

I need to write out a file to a certain path that contains a special character in R. the path is something like this: `C:/Users/Technology ＆ Innovation/Webscraping files/US_data/data`

It works totally fine when I access this path through python, but I cannot access the same path in R. And I cannot change this path name or remove '＆' as this path is used by a lot of people. Does anyone have a good idea on how to solve it?

I found out it is '＆' which has subtle difference from '&' that we usually type in through English Keyboard. May be that's the reason causing the problem?

Here is what I have tried:

```
write.csv(df, 'C:/Users/Technology ＆ Innovation/Webscraping files/US_data/data/file.csv').
write.csv(df, 'C:\\Users\\Technology ＆ Innovation\\Webscraping files\\US_data/data/file.csv')
```

Not matter whether I try to read or write a file, it is not working in my case.

I also tried reset the working directory path and got the error message:

> Error in setwd("C:/Users/Technology & Innovation/Webscraping files/US_data/data") : cannot change working directory

Comment: What functions are you trying to use with that path? What exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: I use write.csv()

Comment: I tried reset the work dictionary as well and it is not working. I got the error message like this : Error in setwd("C:/Users/Technology & Innovation/Webscraping files/US_data/data") : 
  cannot change working directory

Comment: what do you get from `list.dirs("C:/Users", recursive=FALSE)`?   Can you set the working directory interactively via `setwd(choose.dir())` ? (I'm not suggesting this as a solution, just hoping to help diagnose the problem)

Comment: I don't have any problem writing to a folder with a "&" in the path on my windows 10 machine. Are you sure you actually have permissions to write to that user account's home directory? Is that the user you are currently logged in as?

Comment: Hey Mr Flick, yes, I do have the permission to write in the folder. I also write in the files through python in the same folder. I think that is because it is '＆' instead of '&' in the path. I copied '＆' directly from the path, and it doesn't looks like written in English keyboard. Can you tell the subtle difference from what I typed in?

Comment: Ben, thanks for giving the suggestion, here is what I got after type in 'list.dirs("C:/Users", recursive=FALSE)': 'character(0)'. Also, I have tried 'setwd(choose.dir())' as well, and I got the same error message as resetting the work dictionary. So sad! :/

Answer (score 0):

Write it like this

```
C:\\Users\\Technology ＆ Innovation\\Webscraping files\\US_data\\data
```

also, you can change your current directory.[image]

Changing your current directory will help you because you can write read.csv("filename.csv") or write.csv(name_of_file, "filename.csv") as it is without mentioning path.

If you have to write a file you have to use syntax properly.

```
write.csv(C:\\Users\\Technology ＆ Innovation\\Webscraping files\\US_data\\data,"filename.csv")
```

Comment: I tried changing the path as above. write.csv('C:\\Users\\Technology ＆ Innovation\\Webscraping files\\US_data/data/file.csv')  But this is still not working. :/    I hope not to change the work dictionary as I need to schedule running the script each week automatically. I guess the work dictionary would not be set automatically each time when running the script??

Comment: Also, I tried to go to the corresponding folder and reset the working dictionary, and I got the error that I cannot reset it. So sad!!

Comment: You want to write or read? if you want to write you are using it wrongly, after giving a path you have to specify fill name as well.

Comment: Sorry, it was typo. I mean write.csv(df, 'C:\\Users\\Technology ＆ Innovation\\Webscraping files\\US_data/data/file.csv'). Not matter it is reading or writing file, this method is not working in my case. :/

Comment: @WenqingWu If that's not working what is the error coming. I have checked it myself you are doing something wrong.